# How can I download a folder that contains spaces in its name?

Tags: bash, downloads, scp

I use this command to download a folder from another server:

```
scp -r username@server:~/folder1/folder2/”Folder with spaces”
```

It doesn't work, however for a folder without spaces it works.

Edit: The folder contains many spaces and [], so escaping each one would be hard to. I tried without luck.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `"` but `”` (those are slanted). Probably due to a copy/paste from a website.

```
scp -r username@server:~/folder1/folder2/"Folder with spaces" .
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape spase by \ :

```
scp -r username@server:~/folder1/folder2/Folder\ with\ spaces/ .
```

Comment: The problem is that there's many spaces and other things that I need to escape, so the " make things so much smoother.